# How to do arithmetic operation on very large numbers

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to add several 50-digit numbers from an array of strings and print first 10 digit of the summation,but I am getting the wrong answer.What is wrong with my code?
The answer should be: 5537376230
My answer is :3737623039
p.s. i have used the array to store single digits of the summation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string num[100] = {
    "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250",
    "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538",
    "74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629",
    "91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250",
    "23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676",
    "89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757",
    "28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738",
    "44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318",
    "47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276",
    "70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951",
    "62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331",
    "64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178",
    "92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407",
    "58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828",
    "80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390",
    "35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586",
    "86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829",
    "71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938",
    "54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604",
    "53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145",
    "36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721",
    "45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045",
    "17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412",
    "81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692",
    "51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483",
    "62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691",
    "15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209",
    "55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126",
    "18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515",
    "80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954",
    "78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581",
    "16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984",
    "48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030",
    "87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332",
    "59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210",
    "69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085",
    "41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271",
    "65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375",
    "35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307",
    "94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275",
    "88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271",
    "25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526",
    "36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962",
    "24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141",
    "91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403",
    "34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470",
    "23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583",
    "11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470",
    "63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533",
    "67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822",
    "95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774",
    "76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236",
    "37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967",
    "23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522",
    "29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501",
    "18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715",
    "38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381",
    "34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539",
    "40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635",
    "29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903",
    "41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922",
    "62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457",
    "23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519",
    "86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672",
    "11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308",
    "82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581",
    "97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500",
    "42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327",
    "55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789",
    "32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886",
    "75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337",
    "62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731",
    "32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504",
    "99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622",
    "73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724",
    "76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818",
    "97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852",
    "87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090",
    "10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786",
    "71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039",
    "62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116",
    "66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411",
    "60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714",
    "85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096",
    "66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297",
    "64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252",
    "16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011",
    "94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791",
    "78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699",
    "15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078",
    "40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353",
    "44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535",
    "41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954",
    "81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280",
    "82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608",
    "22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197",
    "77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617",
    "72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516",
    "20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722",
    "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690",
  };
    long long sum[100];
    int runner=0;
    long long carry=0;
    for(int l=49;l>=0;l--)
    {
        int total=0;
        for(int k=0;k<100;k++ )
        {
            total+=(int)num[k][l]-48;
        }
        total=total+carry;
        sum[runner]=total%10;
        if(total>9)carry=total/10;
        else carry=0;
        runner++;
    }
    //cout<<runner<<endl;
    for(int l=runner-1;l>runner-11;l--)
    {
        cout<<sum[l];
    }
}
```

Comment: This question shouldn't be on hold. It satisfies all requirements. It contains a full but short working example, and states the expected and actual output.

Answer (score 2):

After your last loop, the carry is 55, but you never insert it into the result.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need the first `10` digits

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    char *num[100] = {
        "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250",
        "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538",
        "74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629",
        "91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250",
        "23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676",
        "89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757",
        "28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738",
        "44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318",
        "47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276",
        "70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951",
        "62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331",
        "64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178",
        "92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407",
        "58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828",
        "80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390",
        "35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586",
        "86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829",
        "71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938",
        "54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604",
        "53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145",
        "36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721",
        "45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045",
        "17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412",
        "81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692",
        "51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483",
        "62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691",
        "15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209",
        "55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126",
        "18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515",
        "80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954",
        "78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581",
        "16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984",
        "48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030",
        "87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332",
        "59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210",
        "69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085",
        "41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271",
        "65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375",
        "35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307",
        "94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275",
        "88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271",
        "25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526",
        "36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962",
        "24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141",
        "91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403",
        "34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470",
        "23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583",
        "11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470",
        "63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533",
        "67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822",
        "95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774",
        "76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236",
        "37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967",
        "23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522",
        "29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501",
        "18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715",
        "38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381",
        "34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539",
        "40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635",
        "29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903",
        "41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922",
        "62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457",
        "23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519",
        "86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672",
        "11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308",
        "82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581",
        "97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500",
        "42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327",
        "55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789",
        "32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886",
        "75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337",
        "62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731",
        "32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504",
        "99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622",
        "73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724",
        "76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818",
        "97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852",
        "87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090",
        "10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786",
        "71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039",
        "62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116",
        "66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411",
        "60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714",
        "85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096",
        "66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297",
        "64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252",
        "16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011",
        "94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791",
        "78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699",
        "15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078",
        "40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353",
        "44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535",
        "41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954",
        "81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280",
        "82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608",
        "22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197",
        "77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617",
        "72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516",
        "20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722",
        "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690",
    };

    long int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
    {
        char firstDigits[15];

        memcpy(firstDigits, num[i], 14);
        firstDigits[14] = 0;

        sum += strtol(firstDigits, NULL, 10);
    }
    char string[11];

    snprintf(string, 11, "%ld", sum);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is guaranteed to work. What if the first 15 digits of each number were to sum to 111111111199999, and the carry from the remaining digits were 1? In that case the real answer would be 1111111112, not 111111111 as you would get here.

Comment: Only the last digit will be subject to this, so it is pretty safe. Since the last digit is `4` digits after the 10th.

Comment: iharob: Aren't all digits subject to this? If my example had been 999999999999985 and carry from the ignored digits were 15, then the correct result would be 1000000000, not 9999999999. But yes, this should not happen very often

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only problem, but you are using 'int' which has the following range:

–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Your numbers are to big and will therefore not work as desired.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx to se the available data-types

Comment: You are absolutely right, he's using an array, therefore my answer is obsolete...

Comment: u have not understood my code.... i have used the array to store single digits of the summation... u can change the array to long long and see no change

Comment: @newbie it's up to you to explain the code if you want answers. It's even mentioned in the rules somewhere. The many downvote and close votes should suggest that something is wrong with the question

Comment: sorry.... now i have edited... @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

You're implicitly assuming that the answer will have no more digits than each of the inputs, which clearly doesn't hold in this case. You do allocate 100 digits for the output, which is more than sufficient, but you never fill more than 50 of them. I've had a go at modifying your code to remedy this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const int nnum = 100, idigits = 50, odigits = 100;
  string num[nnum] = {
    "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250",
    "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538",
    "74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629",
    "91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250",
    "23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676",
    "89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757",
    "28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738",
    "44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318",
    "47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276",
    "70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951",
    "62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331",
    "64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178",
    "92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407",
    "58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828",
    "80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390",
    "35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586",
    "86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829",
    "71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938",
    "54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604",
    "53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145",
    "36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721",
    "45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045",
    "17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412",
    "81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692",
    "51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483",
    "62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691",
    "15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209",
    "55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126",
    "18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515",
    "80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954",
    "78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581",
    "16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984",
    "48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030",
    "87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332",
    "59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210",
    "69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085",
    "41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271",
    "65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375",
    "35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307",
    "94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275",
    "88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271",
    "25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526",
    "36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962",
    "24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141",
    "91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403",
    "34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470",
    "23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583",
    "11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470",
    "63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533",
    "67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822",
    "95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774",
    "76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236",
    "37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967",
    "23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522",
    "29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501",
    "18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715",
    "38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381",
    "34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539",
    "40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635",
    "29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903",
    "41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922",
    "62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457",
    "23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519",
    "86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672",
    "11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308",
    "82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581",
    "97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500",
    "42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327",
    "55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789",
    "32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886",
    "75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337",
    "62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731",
    "32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504",
    "99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622",
    "73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724",
    "76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818",
    "97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852",
    "87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090",
    "10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786",
    "71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039",
    "62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116",
    "66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411",
    "60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714",
    "85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096",
    "66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297",
    "64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252",
    "16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011",
    "94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791",
    "78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699",
    "15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078",
    "40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353",
    "44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535",
    "41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954",
    "81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280",
    "82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608",
    "22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197",
    "77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617",
    "72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516",
    "20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722",
    "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690",
  };
  int sum[odigits];
  int carry=0, d;
  for(d=0;d<odigits;d++)
  {
    int ipos = idigits-1-d;
    int opos = odigits-1-d;
    int total = carry;
    if(ipos >= 0)
      for(int k = 0; k < nnum; k++)
        total += num[k][ipos]-48;
    else if(carry == 0) break;
    sum[opos] = total%10;
    carry = total/10;
  }
  for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << sum[odigits-d+i];
  cout << "\n";
}
```

This produces the desired result 5537376230.

Since an int can hold much more than just 1 decimal digit, a more efficient approach would be to process larger groups of digits at once.